# Android google calendar deleting future instances of recurring event

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, android-contentresolver, recurring-events, rrule

I'm trying to delete future instances of a google calendar recurring (repeated) event pro-grammatically using content resolver.

And to do this i have updated the rRule of the event , so for example if want to delete future instances of an event starting from date 11/11/2016
i edit the rRule string to look like so:

```
 FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20161111;WKST=SU
```

However , when viewing google calendar application i find no changes and i find the event color only has changed to black color.

Some notes to keep in mind:

1- I'm using a third party library to so :
https://github.com/EverythingMe/easy-content-providers

```
CalendarProvider calendarProvider = new CalendarProvider(context);
Event event = calendarProvider.getEvent(eventId);
event.rRule = "FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20161111;WKST=SU";
calendarProvider.update(event);
```

and all functionalities in this library seem to work fine.

2- While reading pro-grammatically recurring events that have a specific UNTIL date in it's rRule , i have realized that also a field in the google event called "lastDate" is updated with one hour later after the UNTIL value ,so do i have to update also this field while updating the UNTIL value in the rRule?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the library ,

```
calendarProvider.update(event);
```

does not seems to work with all event fields!